# Will a LGA 775 socket processor work on a modern motherboard?

Tags: cpu, desktop-computer, computer-building, processor-socket

I'm a guy who really likes old stuff since I'm using a modern motherboard with newer socket(I think it's probably 1366 or 1356 not sure). So I was browsing the internet and saw couple of Pentium 4 and D's for a really cheap price and I was planning to make cheap computer builds(I like to do that) and that's why I'm curious to know if the older processors would work with the newer processor sockets. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No; It will not.  Processors can work in the socket designed for them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't. "Different socket" *literally* means that the CPUs use different electric connections – different sizes, pin counts and locations, signals, etc. Compare LGA 775 and LGA 1366:

[image: LGA 775]
[image: LGA 1366]

Comment: It's worse than that. The CPUs literally perform different functions. An LGA 775 CPU has no memory controller. Modern motherboards have no memory controller on the board because modern CPUs have an on-die memory controller. So there would be no memory controller. How could that work?